# hide devider between child and parent view of expandable list

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to remove divider between child and parent when i expand list view, although i remove childdivider from list 
but this divider is still showing

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/glist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:childDivider="#00000000"
        android:divider="@drawable/line"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this and check it.

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp" //(or)0px
```